# Broadcasting and receiving extra doubles

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, adb

I'm attempting to broadcast extras in an am broadcast in adb shell. In my BroadcastReceiver in android, I'm subscribed to the broadcast and pull the extras out of the Bundle.

My trouble lies with doubles. I assumed that a broadcast could include a double since the `Bundle` class has a `getDouble` method, e.g.:

```
double percentComplete = bundle.getDouble("percent_complete");
```

However, the am broadcast command in adb shell doesn't seem to support doubles, only floats. When I send the float, the Bundle.getDouble() method throws an internal exception, logged at the warning level, indicating that it fails to cast Float to Double.

Can I send doubles, or am I forced to use floats?

Here are the flags for specifiying extras that I am aware of, as reported by am.

```
<INTENT> specifications include these flags and arguments:
    [-a <ACTION>] [-d <DATA_URI>] [-t <MIME_TYPE>]
    [-c <CATEGORY> [-c <CATEGORY>] ...]
    [-e|--es <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_STRING_VALUE> ...]
    [--esn <EXTRA_KEY> ...]
    [--ez <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_BOOLEAN_VALUE> ...]
    [--ei <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_INT_VALUE> ...]
    [--el <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_LONG_VALUE> ...]
    [--ef <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_FLOAT_VALUE> ...]
    [--eu <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_URI_VALUE> ...]
    [--ecn <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_COMPONENT_NAME_VALUE>]
    [--eia <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_INT_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_INT_VALUE...]]
    [--ela <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_LONG_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_LONG_VALUE...]]
    [--efa <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_FLOAT_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_FLOAT_VALUE...]]
    [-n <COMPONENT>] [-f <FLAGS>]
    [--grant-read-uri-permission] [--grant-write-uri-permission]
    [--debug-log-resolution] [--exclude-stopped-packages]
    [--include-stopped-packages]
    [--activity-brought-to-front] [--activity-clear-top]
    [--activity-clear-when-task-reset] [--activity-exclude-from-recents]
    [--activity-launched-from-history] [--activity-multiple-task]
    [--activity-no-animation] [--activity-no-history]
    [--activity-no-user-action] [--activity-previous-is-top]
    [--activity-reorder-to-front] [--activity-reset-task-if-needed]
    [--activity-single-top] [--activity-clear-task]
    [--activity-task-on-home]
    [--receiver-registered-only] [--receiver-replace-pending]
    [--selector]
    [<URI> | <PACKAGE> | <COMPONENT>]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `URI` format to provide `<INTENT>` to `am broadcast` and `am startservice`:

```
adb shell am broadcast "intent:#Intent;action=android.intent.action.YOUR_ACTION;d.percent_complete=99.999;end"
```

`URI` format [supports](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/Intent.java) the following `extra` types:

```
Bundle b = intent.mExtras;
if      (uri.startsWith("S.", i)) b.putString(key, value);
else if (uri.startsWith("B.", i)) b.putBoolean(key, Boolean.parseBoolean(value));
else if (uri.startsWith("b.", i)) b.putByte(key, Byte.parseByte(value));
else if (uri.startsWith("c.", i)) b.putChar(key, value.charAt(0));
else if (uri.startsWith("d.", i)) b.putDouble(key, Double.parseDouble(value));
else if (uri.startsWith("f.", i)) b.putFloat(key, Float.parseFloat(value));
else if (uri.startsWith("i.", i)) b.putInt(key, Integer.parseInt(value));
else if (uri.startsWith("l.", i)) b.putLong(key, Long.parseLong(value));
else if (uri.startsWith("s.", i)) b.putShort(key, Short.parseShort(value));
else throw new URISyntaxException(uri, "unknown EXTRA type", i);
```

Comment: is it possible to use startactivity instead of broadcast that way? adb shell am startservice -a com.something.test.START -e len 5. This fails with invalid cast from string to double

Comment: While executing sample code I got this error         
Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=intent: flg=0x400000 }
Broadcast completed: result=0
/system/bin/sh: d.percent_complete=99.999: inaccessible or not found
/system/bin/sh: end: inaccessible or not found