# Intent anchor syntax description

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to use the intent anchor to launch my app as described [here](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents). I'm able to get it to launch my app using this syntax,

```
<a href="intent://#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.example.myapp;end">Launch my app</a>
```

but I have no idea what many of the various elements mean.

The basic syntax for an intent-based URI is as follows:

> intent:
>
> > ```
> > HOST/URI-path // Optional host 
> > #Intent; 
> >   package=[string]; 
> >    action=[string]; 
> >    category=[string]; 
> >    component=[string]; 
> >    scheme=[string]; 
> > end;
> > ```

1. what do each of the segments mean (so I know how I may best use take advantage of them)
2. how/where can I include any extra data (ie, my own parameters)

Comment: This structure is largely undocumented. A far better solution, instead of hand-crafting the URL, is to create an `Intent` object in Java that would do what you want, then call `toUri()` on it to generate the URL to use. Also note that not all browsers will recognize this URL structure.

Comment: Please explain your recommendation a little further. Do you mean JavaScript? I wouldn't imagine JavaScript supports Intents and you can't guarantee Java is installed on the client.

Comment: "Do you mean JavaScript?" -- no, I mean Java. Android applications usually are written using the Java programming language. Create an Android application, in Java, that creates an `Intent` object that would do what you want, then call `toUri()` on it to generate the URL to use.

Comment: Right, but I need to launch the App from the browser. Are you saying to basically reverse engineer the link I need?

Comment: regardless of full support or not, do you know how to include extras using this structure? I suppose I can throw a string in the `scheme` tag and try parsing that out...

Comment: "I need to launch the App from the browser" -- well, what you're doing will only work for some browsers. There are many browsers for Android, not all of which will support the `intent` scheme, as that is not an IETF standard scheme. "Are you saying to basically reverse engineer the link I need?" -- not really. I am saying that since that URL structure is not documented, you should not be trying to craft such a URL by hand. The "documentation" is Android itself, so have it create the URL for you that you can paste into your HTML.

Comment: "do you know how to include extras using this structure?" -- that is not documented, though there appears to be some support for it in `parseUri()` (the inverse of `toUri()`). You can read the source code to `parseUri()` on `Intent` and try to make sense of it, then hand-craft the URL based on your interpretation of that source code, since you seem reticent to have Android do the hard work for you.

Comment: Do I require any intent filters for this to work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the method `toUri()` from the `Intent` class:

```
public String toUri(int flags) {
    StringBuilder uri = new StringBuilder(128);
    String scheme = null;
    if (mData != null) {
        String data = mData.toString();
        if ((flags&URI_INTENT_SCHEME) != 0) {
            final int N = data.length();
            for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
                char c = data.charAt(i);
                if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
                        || c == '.' || c == '-') {
                    continue;
                }
                if (c == ':' && i > 0) {
                    // Valid scheme.
                    scheme = data.substring(0, i);
                    uri.append("intent:");
                    data = data.substring(i+1);
                    break;
                }
                // No scheme.
                break;
            }
        }
        uri.append(data);
    } else if ((flags&URI_INTENT_SCHEME) != 0) {
        uri.append("intent:");
    }
    uri.append("#Intent;");
    if (scheme != null) {
        uri.append("scheme=").append(scheme).append(';');
    }
    if (mAction != null) {
        uri.append("action=").append(Uri.encode(mAction)).append(';');
    }
    if (mCategories != null) {
        for (String category : mCategories) {
            uri.append("category=").append(Uri.encode(category)).append(';');
        }
    }
    if (mType != null) {
        uri.append("type=").append(Uri.encode(mType, "/")).append(';');
    }
    if (mFlags != 0) {
        uri.append("launchFlags=0x").append(Integer.toHexString(mFlags)).append(';');
    }
    if (mPackage != null) {
        uri.append("package=").append(Uri.encode(mPackage)).append(';');
    }
    if (mComponent != null) {
        uri.append("component=").append(Uri.encode(
                mComponent.flattenToShortString(), "/")).append(';');
    }
    if (mSourceBounds != null) {
        uri.append("sourceBounds=")
                .append(Uri.encode(mSourceBounds.flattenToString()))
                .append(';');
    }
    if (mExtras != null) {
        for (String key : mExtras.keySet()) {
            final Object value = mExtras.get(key);
            char entryType =
                    value instanceof String    ? 'S' :
                    value instanceof Boolean   ? 'B' :
                    value instanceof Byte      ? 'b' :
                    value instanceof Character ? 'c' :
                    value instanceof Double    ? 'd' :
                    value instanceof Float     ? 'f' :
                    value instanceof Integer   ? 'i' :
                    value instanceof Long      ? 'l' :
                    value instanceof Short     ? 's' :
                    '\0';
            if (entryType != '\0') {
                uri.append(entryType);
                uri.append('.');
                uri.append(Uri.encode(key));
                uri.append('=');
                uri.append(Uri.encode(value.toString()));
                uri.append(';');
            }
        }
    }
    uri.append("end");
    return uri.toString();
}
```

If you can read Java code then it should be pretty clear what is going on here. In any case, extras can be put in the URL and they look something like this:

```
<type>.<key>=<value>;
```

where `<type>` is one of the following:

```
S = String
B = Boolean
b = Byte
c = Character
d = Double
f = Float
i = Integer
l = Long
s = Short
```

Here are a few examples:

Launch app:

```
<a href="intent://#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.example.myapp;end">
```

Launch app with one String extra called "foo" containing the value "bar123":

```
<a href="intent://#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.example.myapp;S.foo=bar123;end">
```

Launch app with a String extra called "foo" containing the value "bar123" and an Integer extra called "number" containing the value "-567":

```
<a href="intent://#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.example.myapp;S.foo=bar123;i.number=-567;end">
```

Comment: Very cool, thank you! And it looks like I can get the data out using `.getStringExtra("foo");`

Comment: Can't embed array type extra to uri :(

Comment: @KenIchi You can't have everything! Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @DavidWasser Since I want to pass double extra via `adb am` command, but [am doesn't have option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21732617/1562087) for that, I have to use uri format, in addition to some array extras, but that's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

As at android 28, the API has changed. Here is what the `toUri` code has been changed to:

```
public String toUri(@UriFlags int flags) {
    StringBuilder uri = new StringBuilder(128);
    if ((flags&URI_ANDROID_APP_SCHEME) != 0) {
        if (mPackage == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Intent must include an explicit package name to build an android-app: "
                    + this);
        }
        uri.append("android-app://");
        uri.append(mPackage);
        String scheme = null;
        if (mData != null) {
            scheme = mData.getScheme();
            if (scheme != null) {
                uri.append('/');
                uri.append(scheme);
                String authority = mData.getEncodedAuthority();
                if (authority != null) {
                    uri.append('/');
                    uri.append(authority);
                    String path = mData.getEncodedPath();
                    if (path != null) {
                        uri.append(path);
                    }
                    String queryParams = mData.getEncodedQuery();
                    if (queryParams != null) {
                        uri.append('?');
                        uri.append(queryParams);
                    }
                    String fragment = mData.getEncodedFragment();
                    if (fragment != null) {
                        uri.append('#');
                        uri.append(fragment);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        toUriFragment(uri, null, scheme == null ? Intent.ACTION_MAIN : Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                mPackage, flags);
        return uri.toString();
    }
    String scheme = null;
    if (mData != null) {
        String data = mData.toString();
        if ((flags&URI_INTENT_SCHEME) != 0) {
            final int N = data.length();
            for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
                char c = data.charAt(i);
                if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
                        || (c >= '0' && c <= '9') || c == '.' || c == '-' || c == '+') {
                    continue;
                }
                if (c == ':' && i > 0) {
                    // Valid scheme.
                    scheme = data.substring(0, i);
                    uri.append("intent:");
                    data = data.substring(i+1);
                    break;
                }

                // No scheme.
                break;
            }
        }
        uri.append(data);

    } else if ((flags&URI_INTENT_SCHEME) != 0) {
        uri.append("intent:");
    }

    toUriFragment(uri, scheme, Intent.ACTION_VIEW, null, flags);

    return uri.toString();
}
```

This shows that the chosen answer will no longer work.

Check [this answer by David Wasser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33297988) for a working solution.