# how to use the intent anchor to launch my app with extra data(parameters) in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have ever tried to launch my app using URI schema in javascript like this:

```
window.location = "myapp://api/image?imageurl=hogehoge"
```

but it failed  in android.I don't know why. it's ok in iphone...

so I changed to use the intent anchor to launch my app in android as described here. I'm able to get it to launch my app using this syntax,

```
<a href="intent://#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.example.myapp;end">Launch my app</>
```

but if I use the intent anchor , how can I pass the extra data `("api/image?imageurl=hogehoge")` ?

maybe i can add `"S.imageurl=hogehoge"` to the href but how can i pass this →`"api/image?"`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23253200/769265 for a detailed description of how to add extras.

Comment: You might try something like this: `<a href="intent://api/image?imageurl=hogehoge#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.example.myapp;end">Launch my app</a>`

Comment: @DavidWasser thank you! it worked!if i want to add more parameters ,can i use like this ? <a href="intent://api/image?imageurl=hogehoge&parameter1=value1&paremeter2=value2#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.exampl‌​e.myapp;end">Launch my app</a>

Comment: Yes, should work. I've created an answer so that the question doesn't end up in the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<a href="intent://api/image?imageurl=hogehoge#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.exampl‌​e.myapp;end">Launch my app</a>
```